# cannot display online and offline users on the map

Tags: android

I was trying to display online and offline shops but the problem is it display the shops perfectly but when I click on the switch button to on/off, the markers will show green as well as red both the color

```
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
   map=googleMap;
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);
    }
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    databaseReference.orderByChild("action").equalTo("open").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       for(DataSnapshot shops:dataSnapshot.getChildren() )
       {
           shoplocation shop=shops.getValue(shoplocation.class);
           LatLng sydney = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(shop.getLat()),Double.parseDouble(shop.getLon()));
           map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title(shop.getShopname()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(
                   BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN
           )));
           map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));


       }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    databaseReference.orderByChild("action").equalTo("close").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot shops:dataSnapshot.getChildren() )
            {
                shoplocation shop=shops.getValue(shoplocation.class);
                LatLng sydney = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(shop.getLat()),Double.parseDouble(shop.getLon()));
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title(shop.getShopname()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(
                        BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED
                )));
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));


            }
```

This is the side where the shops are on/off
[The part where shops are on/off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZc3M.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In yours `ValueEventListener`, you always add new markers. But never remove already added ones.
So when the data changes, you add new markers above already added markers.

You can make only one `ValueEventListener` with begin by remove all markers before adding markers red and green.

Somethings like (not tested):

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  googleMap.clear()
  for(DataSnapshot shops:dataSnapshot.getChildren() )
  {
    shoplocation shop=shops.getValue(shoplocation.class);
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(...);
    map.addMarker(...);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
  }
}
```